# Best Practices: Adding properties to a LINQ-to-Entities query result?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, asp.net-webpages

I'm writing an ASP.NET Web Pages application and in it, I have a massive LINQ to Entities query.  This query pulls data from a table in the database, filters it, groups the data twice, and adds extra properties to the result set.  I then loop through the table, outputting the rows.

The query is quite big, sorry:

```
accountOrders = db.EventOrders
    .Where(order => order.EventID == eventID)
    .OrderBy(order => order.ProductCode)
    .GroupBy(order => new { order.AccountNum, order.Exhibitor, order.Booth })
    .Select(orders => 
        new {
            Key = orders.Key,
            ProductOrders = orders
                .GroupBy(order => new { order.ProductCode, order.Product, order.Price })
                .Select(productOrders => 
                    new {
                        Key = productOrders.Key,
                        Quantity = productOrders.Sum(item => item.Quantity),
                        HtmlID = String.Join(",", productOrders.Select(o => (o.OrderNum + "-" + o.OrderLine))),

                        AssignedLines = productOrders.SelectMany(order => order.LineAssignments)
                    })
        })
        .Select(account => 
            new { 
                Key = account.Key,

                // Property to see whether a booth number should be displayed
                HasBooth = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(account.Key.Booth),

                HasAssignedDigitalLines = account.ProductOrders.Any(order => order.AssignedLines.Any(line => line.Type == "digital")),

                // Dividing the orders into their respective product group
                PhoneOrders      = account.ProductOrders.Where(prod => ProductCodes.PHONE_CODES.Contains(prod.Key.ProductCode)),
                InternetOrders   = account.ProductOrders.Where(prod => ProductCodes.INTERNET_CODES.Contains(prod.Key.ProductCode)),
                AdditionalOrders = account.ProductOrders.Where(prod => ProductCodes.ADDITIONAL_CODES.Contains(prod.Key.ProductCode))
            })
        .ToList();
```

I use the added properties to help style the output.  For example, I use HasBooth property to check whether or not I should output the booth location in brackets beside the exhibitor name. The problem is I have to save this big query as an IEnumerable, meaning I get the error: *Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.* Should I even be manipulating the query this way?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point, you are passing in a dynamic datatype to the method, which in turn changes the return type to simply `dynamic`. You can either cast the dynamic type to a type that is recognised at compile time or explicitly set the return type instead of using `var`.

You can read more about this issue here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/198/Cannot-use-a-lambda-expression-as-an-argument-to-a-dynamically-dispatched-operation